# 'Manipulate' keeps updating output even though the manipulated variable has not changed

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

Why is the following code keeping updating an output with increasing variable `v`, even though I have not changed the manipulated variable `q`?

It just loads the processor unnecessarily when nothing is being changed in `Manipulate`.

I would expect it to update and increase the variable `v` only when manipulation to the `q` was done.

Is this a correct behavior or a bug? If it is a correct behavior, how can I prevent it?

```
v = 1;
Manipulate[v = v + 1, {q, 0, 10, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is expected. The fix is this:

```
v = 1;
Manipulate[
 v = v + 1,
 {q, 0, 10, 1},
 TrackedSymbols :> {q}]
```

It happens, because Manipulate will always run the expression the very first time. This is what Manipulate does all its life: it checks if the variable in the expression changed its value (most common, due to changing the slider). If so, it then updates the expression.

Since you did not tell which variables to track its changes, it then tracks a change of any variable.

So it goes into a loop. It changes `v` to new value. Then looks again and finds `v` changed. It then updates the expression. Then it looks again and find `v` changed again. Then it updates the expression. And so on forever.

One way to prevent this is to always add `TrackedSymbols` to tell it which variables to track and only update the expression if these are changed.

> But then the output is always 2. I want increase of v on every change
> of q

In this case, you need to explicitly have `q` appear in the expression, like this

```
v = 1;
Manipulate[
 q;
 v = v + 1,
 {q, 0, 10, 1},
 TrackedSymbols :> {q}]
```

[image]

> Is it guaranteed that v increases only once on each change of q in the
> second version of your code?

Yes. Each time q changes, it will run the expression again. You can see this more easily by opening the little window and increment `q` using the `+` button:

[image]

Comment: But then the output is always `2`. I want increase of `v` on every change of `q`.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `v` increases only once on each change of `q` in the second version of your code?

Comment: I see, but is it impossible that `v` would be increased, say twice, on single change of `q`?

Comment: It would be more suitable for me to have option like `NotTrackedSymbols` than `TrackedSymbols`.

Comment: It shouldn't happen that `v` updates twice on a single update of `q`, however, `v`  could be updated in other ways. If somewhere else in your notebook you evaluated `v=100`, then on the next update of `q` you'd see `101`.

Answer (score 4):

Manipulate is basically a fancy [Dynamic](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html), so this is expected. It can be fraught to use Dynamics that have side effects. You can "hide" the `v` from the Manipulate like this:

```
v = 1;
counter[_] := ++v;
Manipulate[counter[q], {q, 0, 10, 1}]
```

TrackedSymbols is more explicit (see Nasser's answer).